# How to Store an XML Data in Grid View Using objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to Store the XML data into an Common String Value. And I need an help to store the XML Data in an Grid View using Objective C and Display the XML data.

Comment: you can parse the xml data and store it in string/array/dictionary. Grid View means - Collection view?. You tried anything ?.

Comment: No because i an new to iOS , so i don't have any idea if u have any basic code for this method means it will vey help full to me .
Yes Grid View means Collection View.

Comment: Refer https://www.google.co.in/#safe=off&q=ios+parse+xml  and https://www.google.co.in/#safe=off&q=ios+collection+view+example

Comment: Your XML Parsing is Done? if Done then store parse data in array, and pass this array to your collection view.

Comment: Thanks PallaviNikumbh